# VB.net read XML element

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to write an application in VB.net but I stuck and I spend some time searching how to do this but can't get it.
What i need is read specific xml element and write it in to the specific label. If someone can give me an example.

I need output like this:

```
--Book 1---
Title: Everyday Italian
Author: Giada De Laurentiis

--Book 2--
Title: Harry Potter
Author: J K. Rowling

--etc--
```

XML:

```
<bookstore>
<book>
    <title>Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book>
    <title>XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book>
    <title>Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
</book>
```

What i need is something like this:
[Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37856803/Untitled.png)

Now is showing only first book. I need to loop all books.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim xmlRoot As XElement = XDocument.Load("x:\books.xml").Root

For Each book As XElement In xmlRoot.<book>
     Debug.WriteLine(book.<title>.Value)
     Debug.WriteLine(book.<author>.Value)
     Debug.WriteLine(book.<year>.Value)
     Debug.WriteLine(book.<price>.Value)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working in console. You know maybe how to make that  in the windows form application?

Comment: You need to create the labels on runtime or create a custom control that can hold and show that info or ... a lot of possibilities :)

Comment: Thanks. Will try now. I think I am on a good way to make it. Thanks again. Can I contact you if I stuck? :)

Comment: Best is asking here, there are lot more capable people around than me :D